# The.NET program issues "failed to load files or assemblies" after the Mono.Cecil patch

Tags: c#, .net, clr, patch, mono.cecil

I have a program that uses mono patches for all dll.

When I run it, it throws an exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'xxxxxxx, Version=911.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)".

I have removed strong signatures for all assemblies' strong signatures and related references.

After debugging, the method calls the `GetCustomAttribute` method to throw an exception, which belongs to a member method `GetCustomAttributes` of the `System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider` interface.
I think there's strong signature information in some metadata, but I didn't find it. Where is the strong signature data is kept?

Code:

```
private static IEnumerable<PageFreeHandler.PageFreePageInfo> FindAllPageFreePages(Assembly assembly)
{
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract)
        {
            PageFreeHandler.PageFreePageInfo pageFreePageInfo = new PageFreeHandler.PageFreePageInfo
            {
                PageType = type,
                CanonicalUrlAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<CanonicalUrlAttribute>(),
                AlternateUrlAttributes = new List<AlternateUrlAttribute>(type.GetCustomAttributes<AlternateUrlAttribute>()).ToArray(),
                RegexUrlAttributes = new List<RegexUrlAttribute>(type.GetCustomAttributes<RegexUrlAttribute>()).ToArray()
            };
            if (pageFreePageInfo.CanonicalUrlAttribute != null || pageFreePageInfo.AlternateUrlAttributes.Length != 0 || pageFreePageInfo.RegexUrlAttributes.Length != 0)
            {
                yield return pageFreePageInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    Type[] array = null;
    yield break;
}
```

---

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this ICustomAttributeProvider member) where T : Attribute
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("member");
        }
        object[] customAttributes = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true);
        if (customAttributes.Length != 0)
        {
            return (T)((object)customAttributes[0]);
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetCustomAttributes<T>(this ICustomAttributeProvider member)
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("member");
        }
        return member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true).Cast<T>();
    }

    public static Type[] GetGenericArgumentsFromAncestor(this Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        }
        if (genericTypeDefinition == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("genericTypeDefinition");
        }
        if (!genericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("genericTypeDefinition is not a generic type definition");
        }
        while (!type.IsGenericType || !(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition))
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
            if (!(type != null))
            {
                return Type.EmptyTypes;
            }
        }
        return type.GetGenericArguments();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: I don't understand markdown grammar, but I try to learn it.
But whether I use <pre><code> or Ctrl+K, I can't show my code properly.
Can you teach me?

Comment: I edited your question. Basically, just select the whole block of code and type Ctrl-K. See for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks